# Get notified when an Ndef message has been sent using forground Ndef push?

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s

I'm trying to get two Nexus S devices to exchange Ndef messages bi-directionally, without having to tap the phones for each individual message. I don't think having both devices' foreground push and dispatch enabled is a good idea as the the behaviour might be unpredictable. I thought one way of acheiving this is for the initiator to

1. Disable fg push and fg dispatch
2. Set up Ndef message
3. Enable fg push with the message
4. Disable fg push after message is sent
5. Enable fg dispatch
6. Receive response via intent
7. Disable fg dispatch
8. Goto 2

And analogously for the responder.

The only thing is the current API does not seem to support Step 4, i.e. get notified when message is successfully pushed. Can anyone suggest how it could be done? Or any alternative ways of achieving single-tap P2P?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without the NFC service having to notify message push. Let your application implicitly infer from the response message. Isn't that what you want, the message reaching the peer, and just not pushed over NFC to a device that doesn't understand your message.

1. Enable Foreground push message with your NDEF message only from the initiator, also enable Foreground dispatch
2. Receive the response NDEF message from peer
3. Create new response NDEF message and enable it in foreground push, to continue the next cycle of message exchange
4. Disable Foreground push/Foreground dispatch to terminate communication.

   Additionally you can have NDEF_DISCOVERED filter for the initial trigger (at the receiver), then let the Foreground dispatch take over for subsequent messages.

Hope it helps !!